# PostgreSQL: Sum accumulated over the previous result, which is a calculation, from the same column

Tags: sql, postgresql

My data is:

| ESTADO | USUARIO_ID | EJERCICIO_MES | TIEMPO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABIERTA | USER 1 | 2020-01 | 6 |
| ABIERTA | USER 2 | 2020-01 | 53 |
| ABIERTA | USER 1 | 2020-02 | 48 |
| ABIERTA | USER 2 | 2020-02 | 89 |
| ABIERTA | USER 1 | 2020-03 | 72 |
| ABIERTA | USER 2 | 2020-03 | 54 |
| ABIERTA | USER 3 | 2020-03 | 11 |
| CERRADA | USER 1 | 2020-04 | 35 |
| CERRADA | USER 2 | 2020-04 | 56 |
| CERRADA | USER 3 | 2020-04 | 20 |
| CERRADA | USER 1 | 2020-05 | 78 |
| CERRADA | USER 2 | 2020-04 | 19 |
| CERRADA | USER 3 | 2020-05 | 37 |
| CERRADA | USER 1 | 2020-06 | 79 |
| CERRADA | USER 2 | 2020-06 | 62 |
| CERRADA | USER 3 | 2020-06 | 96 |
| CERRADA | USER 1 | 2020-07 | 57 |
| CERRADA | USER 2 | 2020-07 | 2 |
| CERRADA | USER 3 | 2020-07 | 36 |

I want this new column called RESULTADO:

| ESTADO | USUARIO_ID | EJERCICIO_MES | TIEMPO | RESULTADO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABIERTA | USER 1 | 2020-01 | 6 | 6 |
| ABIERTA | USER 2 | 2020-01 | 53 | 53 |
| ABIERTA | USER 1 | 2020-02 | 48 | 48 |
| ABIERTA | USER 2 | 2020-02 | 89 | 89 |
| ABIERTA | USER 1 | 2020-03 | 72 | 72 |
| ABIERTA | USER 2 | 2020-03 | 54 | 54 |
| ABIERTA | USER 3 | 2020-03 | 11 | 11 |
| CERRADA | USER 1 | 2020-04 | 35 | 1260 |
| CERRADA | USER 2 | 2020-04 | 56 | 1960 |
| CERRADA | USER 3 | 2020-04 | 20 | 110 |
| CERRADA | USER 1 | 2020-05 | 78 | 13860 |
| CERRADA | USER 2 | 2020-04 | 19 | 21560 |
| CERRADA | USER 3 | 2020-05 | 37 | 1210 |
| CERRADA | USER 1 | 2020-06 | 79 | 152460 |
| CERRADA | USER 2 | 2020-06 | 62 | 237160 |
| CERRADA | USER 3 | 2020-06 | 96 | 13310 |
| CERRADA | USER 1 | 2020-07 | 57 | 1677060 |
| CERRADA | USER 2 | 2020-07 | 2 | 2608760 |
| CERRADA | USER 3 | 2020-07 | 36 | 146410 |

Let's look at the example for USER 1:

| ESTADO | USUARIO_ID | EJERCICIO_MES | TIEMPO | RESULTADO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABIERTA | USER 1 | 2020-01 | 6 | 6 |
| ABIERTA | USER 1 | 2020-02 | 48 | 48 |
| ABIERTA | USER 1 | 2020-03 | 72 | 72 |
| CERRADA | USER 1 | 2020-04 | 35 | 1260 |
| CERRADA | USER 1 | 2020-05 | 78 | 13860 |
| CERRADA | USER 1 | 2020-06 | 79 | 152460 |
| CERRADA | USER 1 | 2020-07 | 57 | 1677060 |

The new result field comes from the following combination:

1. When ESTADO = ABIERTA then the result of RESULTADO field is the value of TIEMPO
2. When ESTADO = CERRADA appears for the first time partitioned by user_id then the result of RESULTADO is the cumulative sum of the previous rows (for that user) multiply by 10.
   **So 1260 = (6+48+72)*10**
3. When ESTADO = CERRADA appears the next time partitiones by user_id, then the result of RESULTADO is the cumulative sum of the previous rows when ESTADO = ABIERTA + 1260 (is the cumulative sum of the prevouos one multiply by 10) multiply by 10

So 13860 = ((6+48+72)+((6+48+72)*10))*10
So 152460 = cumulative of previous results * 10

I would like to have a query for the RESULTADO field

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't use T-SQL; I've removed those conflicting tags. Please [edit] your question to (re)tag correctly.

Comment: You also don't *ask* anything. What is your question here? What is the difficulty you're having solving the problem?

Comment: this is my question " I would like to have a query for the RESULTADO field"

Comment: That's not a question. What you describe isn't a cumulative total either. There are SO questions that ask about cumulative totals already and the easy answer is to use the OVER clause, eg `sum(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date) `

Comment: no :( it is not normative cumulative sum... i explained in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive `cte` to build up the cumulative sums:

```
with recursive tbl1 as (
   select row_number() over (order by a.usuario_id, a.estado, a.ejercicio_mes) r, a.* from tbl a
),
a1 as (
   select t.*, case when lower(t.estado) = 'abierta' then t.tiempo 
       when lower(t.estado) = 'cerrada' and t.r = (select min(t1.r) from tbl1 t1 where t1.usuario_id = t.usuario_id and lower(t1.estado) = 'cerrada')
          then (select sum(t1.tiempo) from tbl1 t1 where t1.usuario_id = t.usuario_id and t1.r < t.r and lower(t1.estado) = 'abierta') * 10
       else 0 end resultado 
   from tbl1 t
),
cte as (
   select t2.*, t2.resultado * 10 val from (
    select a.r, a.estado, a.usuario_id, a.ejercicio_mes, a.tiempo, (select sum(a2.resultado) from a1 a2 where a2.usuario_id = a.usuario_id and a2.r < a.r) resultado
    from a1 a where a.resultado = 0 and lower(a.estado) = 'cerrada' 
      and a.r = (select min(a2.r) from a1 a2 where a2.resultado = 0 and lower(a2.estado) = 'cerrada' and a2.usuario_id = a.usuario_id)) t2
    union all
    select a.r, a.estado, a.usuario_id, a.ejercicio_mes, a.tiempo, c.resultado + c.val resultado, (c.resultado + c.val)*10 val
    from tbl1 a join cte c on c.r + 1 = a.r and a.usuario_id = c.usuario_id and lower(a.estado) = 'cerrada'
)
select a.estado, a.usuario_id, a.ejercicio_mes, a.tiempo, a.resultado from a1 a where a.resultado != 0
union all
select a.estado, a.usuario_id, a.ejercicio_mes, a.tiempo, a.val from cte a
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wfSUQLnv)

Comment: It works perfectly!!!!!!!!!!